# Redirect from app page to fan page

Tags: facebook, redirect

Hei.

Is there any other way to redirect users from app page (apps.facebook.com) to the fan pages app site (/pages/example/appid=123456789).

I actually doing it with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function NotInFacebookFrame() {
return top === self;
}
function ReferrerIsFacebookApp() {
if(document.referrer) {
    return document.referrer.indexOf("apps.facebook.com") != -1;
}
return false;
}
if (NotInFacebookFrame() || ReferrerIsFacebookApp()) {
top.location.replace("http://fanpage.com");
}
</script>
```

Because if you get an invite you get sent to the app page, not to the fan page.
But the redirection is slow, and i saw some apps where the redirection is very fast.
Here is the app where it redirects like i want: http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=402068793183793

HOW do i get this redirection message? i can't find any solution....

Best regarts, Andreas.

Comment: Just use top.location = "newurl"

Comment: Frist thanks, but thats not the solution i asked for.

Comment: This is the only solution to redirect from canvas to tab... serverside redirection wont work ...

Comment: You're wrong, i solved it. Adding the Tab URL to "Website using Facebook login" will redirect users from Canvas to Tab!